# How to create a single pdf with multiple Stargazer tables

Tags: r, stargazer

I would like to output multiple stargazer tables into one pdf document, similar to how one can output multiple plots into one pdf document using the pdf() function. I would like to have separate tables with one table for each variable and multiple regressions for each variable.

I tried using the pdf() function and then running the stargazer tables.

```r
merged <- dataset
pdf("regressions.pdf", width = 12, height = 12)

vars <- a list of dependent vars
reg1_vars <- a list of independent vars for first regression
reg2_vars <- a list of independent vars for second regression

for(var in vars){

  formula <- as.formula(paste(var,".new~ .",sep=""))

  group1 <- merged[, unlist(lapply(lapply(substr(colnames(merged),1,3), 
                                          FUN=grepl, c(var, reg1_vars)), any))]
  lm1 <- lm(formula, data = group1) 

  group2 <- merged[, unlist(lapply(lapply(substr(colnames(merged),1,3), 
                                       FUN=grepl, c(var, reg2_vars)), any))]
  lm2 <- lm(formula, data = group2)

  stargazer(lm1,lm2 out = "table.pdf")
}
dev.off()
```

Since the stargazer tables are not graphics, they are not captured in the pdf file.

Answer (score 1):

Stargazer can return html and latex code, so you are probably best off creating an RMarkdown (`.Rmd`) file and using `knitr` to create the pdf ([this](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-1.html) provides a pretty good tutorial).
You can then put your loop into an R code-chunk and also maybe use `cat('\\newpage')` after each stargazer call to tell latex to put the next table on a new page.

Hope that helps.